# How to upload app to appstore which is more than 100MB in size?

Tags: ios, phonegap

I have to upload app on appstore which is 250MB.It contains gif images of 210Mb.Anybody know how to upload such app on Appstore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The apple developer site says your uncompressed app can have maximum of 4 GB size. Its better to use application loader for uploading huge size build;

Please check the developer site [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/SubmittingTheApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH33-SW4). It says

> For iOS and tvOS apps, check that your app size fits within the App
>   Store requirements. Your app’s total uncompressed size must be less
>   than 4GB. Each Mach-O executable file (for example,
>   app_name.app/app_name) must not exceed these limits:
>
> For apps whose MinimumOSVersion is less than 7.0: maximum of 80 MB for
>   the total of all __TEXT sections in the binary.
>
> For apps whose MinimumOSVersion is 7.x through 8.x: maximum of 60 MB
>   per slice for the __TEXT section of each architecture slice in the
>   binary.
>
> For apps whose MinimumOSVersion is 9.0 or greater: maximum of 500 MB
>   for the total of all __TEXT sections in the binary.
>
> However, consider download times when determining your app’s size.
>   Minimize the file’s size as much as possible, keeping in mind that
>   there is a 100 MB limit for over-the-air downloads.

As there is a limit for over the air downloads it is better not to use the gif files in the bundle itself, instead download all the gif files from the app using some webservice which will reduce the size of your app

Comment: Hi,In android there is APK expansion files for app size more than 100mb. Is there any such procedure in iOS?

Comment: No. There is nothing like apk expansion files in IOS. Everything is your one single ipa which is compressed form of your binaries and resources.

Comment: I uploaded build using application loader but it shows build warning. Can I upload build or not? It's not possible me to use webservice for gif images.

Comment: is apple approved that build?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with Application Loader.
Its upload your huge app in app store.

```
 xcode -> preferences -> open developer tools -> application loader
```

using this you will upload your application.

Comment: Hi I uploaded build using application loader but it shows build warning that size is more than 100mb

Comment: Its just a warning. So you will continue with your application upload.

Comment: Ok.Thank you so much